# JScrollPane does not scroll properly: scrollRectToVisible acting up?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have got the following basic setup on a Part of my GUI:

A JScrollPane
On it, a JPanel with a BoxLayout (new BoxLayout(tablePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS))
And on this Panel, a Bunch ob Panels.

I am trying to scroll to the Panel that has been highlighted... this works ALMOST.
Currenly, if a Panel is only half-visible on the bottom Part, the ScrollPane scrolls to make it fully visible.. great.
If it is half-visible on the TOP part, it does not... I could live with that.
But if a totally invisible Panel at the very bottom is highlighted, the system does not comment, but neither does it scroll there!

```
            if(selectedPanel!=null){
            Rectangle targetRectangle = new Rectangle(selectedPanel.getX(), selectedPanel.getY(), selectedPanel.getWidth(), selectedPanel.getHeight());
            Rectangle r = scrollPane.getVisibleRect();
            if (!r.contains(targetRectangle)) {
                tablePanel.scrollRectToVisible(targetRectangle);
            }
        }
```

I am unfortunately not 100% sure how it behaves when the second-to-last panel is selected while not visible, because I cannot make that happen without some code-gymnastics; perhaps someone can help with the information I can give at this point.

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. you have to compare `Rectangle` from/returns `JViewport`(visible rectangle from `JScrollPane`), not from `JScrollPane`
2. use `selectedPanel.getBounds` instead of `(selectedPanel.getX(), selectedPanel.getY(), selectedPanel.getWidth(), selectedPanel.getHeight());`
3. still isn't centerred, have to divide `JVievports` and `selectedPanel` with `2`
4. the same result as to use single code line `JComponentPlacedIntoJScrollPane.scrollRectToVisible(selectedPanel.getBounds())`
5. for better help sooner post an `SSCCE`/`MCVE`, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Very nice my friend. 1+

Comment: 1) That does make sense, yes.. thanks.
2) Ahhh, all right, that certainly makes it a LOT easier to read!!!

Number 1 seems to already have helped... I still have side-effect under certain conditions but I think those are caused by the System I had to push my Panel into.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I will be good and work on SSCCE/MCVE 'S whenever possible in the future :)

Comment: @Layna 1. [I'm sure that there are answers to my points 1-4th.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+scrollRectToVisible), 2. from SSCCE/MCVE is always possible to catch everything (almost)

Comment: Ok, all further problems must come from the outside... I did make a tiny program to test the scrolling-code, and it works now...

As a little note to the answer again:

3 is correct, but we decided against always centering because it made things too jumpy 

Same goe for 4: if we do not check if we need to scroll, things jump all over the place, making us dizzy from lookign at it, so no one-line-solution, neat as it would have been :)

Comment: put scrolling inside invokeLater (used 1. initial thread, 2. notify EDT, 3. moving desired event to the end of EDT)